# Disabled button still fires on touch in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touch

In the Chrome browser, I noticed disabled button elements are still firing when using 'touchend' or 'pointerup' events. I see this on Chrome desktop (mac) in device emulation mode and in Chrome on a Surface. This doesn't seem to be problem on other browsers.

```
// neither of these seem to have an effect on touch/pointer events
button.disabled = true;
button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Obvious fix would to only mouse events, but I'd rather not have the lag time for it to trigger on touch devices. I'm assuming this a Chrome issue and not my code, but I thought I'd ask to see maybe it is me or if others have found a practical work around.

Comment: Could you please set up a, testable https://jsfiddle.net/ so i can take a look at it?

Comment: here's one I already made on CodePen: [link](https://codepen.io/aashby13/pen/YjBpGj)

Comment: What about css `button:disabled { pointer-events: none };`. It works for me..

Comment: @bigless - Yep, that works! Thanks for pointing out the obvious solution and making me feel stupid. hahaha. If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear that.. It is more hotfix than explanation so lets wait if somebody know right answer..

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem and as suggested by @bigless, below CSS worked for me too.

```
button:disabled { pointer-events: none };
```